# Pythonanywhere Web2Py redirect to HTTPS

Tags: python, web2py, pythonanywhere

I have create a webproject Web2Py and would like user to access the pages on normal `http://` instaed of `http://`.

Each time I type `http://domain.pythonanywhere.com` et redirect me to `http://domain.pythonanywhere.com`.

It taces 0.5 sec. to do the SSL check and I would like to avoid that.

This was as default:

```
## if SSL/HTTPS is properly configured and you want all HTTP requests to
## be redirected to HTTPS, uncomment the line below:
# request.requires_https()
```

Answer (score 5):

PythonAnywhere dev here: that looks like a bug on our side.  We "pin" HTTPS for our own site, so that people always go to https://www.pythonanywhere.com/, but it looks like that might have leaked over to customer sites.

Just for clarity -- if someone goes to http://yourusername.pythonanywhere.com/ then we won't initially force it to go to the https site -- they'll get the http one.  But if they then go to https://yourusername.pythonanywhere.com, then their browser will remember that they have visited the https domain, so all future requests will redirect there.

That's actually generally good practice (it works around a number of [security problems](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/HTTP_strict_transport_security)) but we shouldn't be forcing it on people.

[UPDATE] the bug is now fixed, many thanks to boje for pointing us at it :-)  One caveat -- if you've ever visited your site over HTTPS before we applied the fix, then you'll still be forced to HTTPS.  You need to clear your browser history to see the new unpinned behaviour.

Comment: I have tried to incognito the page, and it still jumps from http:// to https://, but if I use IE8 it stay on http://
So maybe it works, but it is hard to found out when it may have been "pin" HTTPS.
Can the sitting be cleared, so all start on fresh? For testing

Comment: Right, I just discovered the same thing about incognito when I was testing a fix for this.  Turns out that the "force HTTPS for this site" setting is carried from your non-incognito sessions into the incognito ones.  The incognito-ness only works in the other direction -- that is, if you first visited the site via HTTPS *inside an incognito session* then the force-HTTPS would not be carried through to the non-incognito sessions.  Which makes sense, I guess.  The same is true of browser history, you can see your non-incognito history in an incognito session.

Comment: Anyway, I've fixed the problem -- the force-HTTPS stuff only works for the PythonAnywhere site itself now, not for your own domain.  But you'll need to clear your browser history to see the change :-(

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue let http:// redirect to https:// And I found google group post on [here](http://Try:https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py-developers/3XY41uBpEgM). The following code maybe give you some ideas on your problem, Under db.py add:

```
############ FORCED SSL #############
from gluon.settings import global_settings
if global_settings.cronjob:
    print 'Running as shell script.'
elif not request.is_https:
    redirect(URL(scheme='https', args=request.args, vars=request.vars))
    session.secure()
#####################################
```

Comment: 1. cronjob is not a concern anymore, since `scheduler` is the way to go. 2. you can create a new model `secure.py`. By this way, you can use `.gitignore` to only have this function on server, but not local `127.0.0.1:8000`